# Key Bindings WPF with Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, visibility, key-bindings

I have a window with a `TabControl`.  I have a `TabItem` where I set:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}
```

I have also added this to the XAML of the window:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl"
                Key="H"
                Command="{Binding ToggleHiddenTab}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I added this method to the ViewModel.

```
public void ToggleHiddenTab()
        {
            if (IsVisible == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                IsVisible = Visibility.Hidden;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsVisible);
            }
            else
            {
                IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsVisible);
            }
        }
```

And the full property:

```
private Visibility _isVisible;
public Visibility IsVisible
        {
            get { return _isVisible; }
            set {
                _isVisible = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsVisible);
            }
        }
```

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> nothing happens.  To test the functionality I added a test button:

```
<Button x:Name="ToggleHiddenTab" Content="Test Visible" 
        Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,8,20,8">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

When I click the button the hidden tab changes its visibility.  Why is the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> key not being accepted?

--------------------- EDIT-------------------------------------------
Per the answer below I added:

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Gesture Ctrl+H] = [ToggleHiddenTab]"
```

Then the editor thru a "namespace undefined" error for "cal:", a quick google search suggested adding to the window tag:

```
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
```

This is still not working as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToggleHiddenTab` is not a command, it's a method.

But you should be able to use the `cal:Message.Attach` attached property to hook up the key binding:

```
<Window ... cal:Message.Attach="[Gesture Ctrl+H] = [ToggleHiddenTab]">
```

Comment: This thu a "cal:" namespace undefined error, I googled the error and was directed to add the name space definition.  I added the code to my original question - under the EDIT line.  This is still not working.

Comment: Update, after adding the above "cal:Message.Attach...." and "cal=......." namespace.  my program was crashing on Initialize for the "Microsoft.Expression.Interaction"  after messing around I found there was 2 versions in my program directory (4.0 & 4.5).  I pulled the project from GitHub on my office computer and it also crashed.  I had to install "Blend" from Nuget to get the application to use 4.5.  Now the program runs but the keybinding does not.

Comment: I marked mm8's answer as correct, that was the best way to handle the issue, however I was missing a lot of other coding.  See the link posted in next answer for a demo from the maker of Caliburn.Micro

Answer (score 2):

The approach with `cal:Message.Attach="[Gesture Ctrl+H]...` doesn't work for me for some reason. But I've found a solution with `KeyTrigger`.

in your case it will be something like:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
xmlns:cm="http://caliburnmicro.com"
...

<Grid >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:KeyTrigger Key="H" Modifiers="Control">
            <cm:ActionMessage MethodName="ToggleHiddenTab" />
        </i:KeyTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    ...     
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got it working.  I forgot all about the examples in Caliburn.Micro's GitHub page.

Namely this one:
https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/master/samples/scenarios/Scenario.KeyBinding

I had to make changes to the AppBootstrapper Configure(), as well as add 4 more class's to the project.

Everything works perfectly now!